# creating a registration and login page with php and mysql on apache server (raspbian jessie)

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, apache

Hello and thanks in advance for the help. I am running a LAMP server on my raspberry pi and I need help creating a registration and login page using mysql database. All my php files have to be in the /var/www/html. I've been googling this for about a week and I have some questions.

- Where do I save css files
- Can I make a subdirectory in the html that will create a website (I have tried to do this already but when i navigate to the site it tells me the page isnt working)
- How do I make it secure (this is for a personal project so it doesnt have to be extremely secure I just want to know some common security issues)

I tried to follow http://www.allphptricks.com/simple-user-registration-login-script-in-php-and-mysqli/ steps and it showed nothing but a blank page.

I am not asking someone to just write all the code for me, I want to learn and understand what I am doing wrong so if you could direct me to a better tutorial or explain it that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First off make sure all of your CSS files paths are set correctly in the HTML files that you are trying to style. As long as the CSS files are included correctly then it should style your page. The final destination of the CSS files should not matter as long as you have the correct path set to the CSS file in the HTML file.

Linking a CSS file to an HTML file [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)
All I did was search "mysql php security best practices" I'm sure you can find more but here is what I found (the first link in my case) [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I feel pretty dumb because about 15 mins after posting the question I found out what my problem was with the css files and its exactly what you said. I guess its one of those things where something doesnt work until you ask someone who knows. Do you know if I create a subdirectory in the html directory if it will show up as a webpage or do I have to have all files directly in the html directory?

Comment: No problem! Were humans we make mistakes. Just make sure to Learn from them! About your second question I don't quite know the answer to that one. On that note google is your friend.